# what does it means that method should be static?

Tags: python, class, methods, static, pycharm

I am a new beginner in computer programming and English is not my first language. When I use Class in python on IDE Pycharm, and it says that method which may safely made static. I don't understand this. Could you tell me what does that mean and how to make the method static? Thank you very much This is my code:

```
class Ga:
def __init__(self, ha):
    self.ha = ha

def ar(self):
    return ade.ha
```

The Python inspection occurs in the 5th line under the 'ar', which is:

```
def ar(self):
```

(I only have 9 reputation so that I can't post any pictures.)

Comment: What is `ade` supposed to be?

Comment: The functions `__init__` and `ar` are not indented in the OP, they were probably in the source.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/136097/1959808

Comment: Methods which do not use `self` in the code can be decorated as `@staticmethod`. This will prevent the injection of the instance as the first positional argument (`self`).